# finding item in Dictionary with list of values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
public class TransactionData

{

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> transactionsAndFilesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public bool FileBlocked(string transactionID, string fileName)
    {
        foreach (var entry in this.transactionsAndFilesDictionary)
        {
            if(entry.Value.Contains(fileName)){
                if(entry.Key==transactionID) return false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have problem with `FileBlocked` method. Line `if(entry.Value.Contains(fileName))`rises exception and I don't know why. I just simply want to check if the `fileName` exists for any `transactionID`.

Comment: What exception is being risen? I'm geussing it is a null one? If it does, you have to make sure that the `Value` of each `entry` is not empty, or null.

Comment: Please show us the code where you add data to `transactionsAndFilesDictionary`.

Comment: Indeed. First time I'm adding transactionID to the Dictionary I'm setting vale to null... my mistake. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Set a breakpoint on the line giving the exception and check if `entry` is `null`.

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is solved.Thank you for your engagement!

Comment: Probably best to delete this altogether, it's not likely to help anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  You dictionary values is a list which I think is the issue

```
   public class TransactionData
    {

        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> transactionsAndFilesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public bool FileBlocked(string transactionID, string fileName)
        {
            foreach (var key in this.transactionsAndFilesDictionary.Keys)
            {
                if (transactionsAndFilesDictionary[key].Where(x => x.Contains(fileName)).Count() > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }​
```

Comment: 4 minutes before I posted with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing - because you didn't show how you add entries to your dictionary - the list is not initialized at the time you invoke the `FileBlocked` method. If that's intentional, that is it's actually in accordance with your business logic to access a dictionary that may be empty than you first have to check if the `Value` exists. `entry.Value != null` should do the trick:

```
foreach (var entry in this.transactionsAndFilesDictionary)
{
    if (entry.Value != null &&
        entry.Value.Contains(fileName)){
        if(entry.Key==transactionID) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If however accessing the `entry.Value` is an unexpected side effect and should never happen then you may be missing a List initialization when you add items to the dictionary.

Make sure that when adding a new `myKey` to the dictionary you initialize the list as well. it's not initialized when you initialize the dictionary:

```
this.transactionsAndFilesDictionary[myKey] = new List<string>();
```